# how to remove characters of String from left in java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a String in java Which contains following characters ..

```
'2010-12-04' and '2013-12-03' and wwid='1234'
```

Now as per my need i have to remove the starting characters of this and make it like..

```
and wwid='1234'
```

I tried it through substring concept where i tried to give the starting point where it needs to be deleted and after that add it into String  but i am not able to get it..

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually substring should work. One thing you need to consider is that **substring does not change the actual string but returns a new string**. So use:

```
String newString = str.substring(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the last Indexof String `and`, and make it as start position to do substring method.

Try

```
   String text = "'2010-12-04' and '2013-12-03' and wwid='1234'";
   text = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("and"));
   System.out.println(text);
```

Output in console:

```
and wwid='1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine [IndexOf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) and [Sustring()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) or use [replace(UndesiredCharSequence, "")](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_replace_sequence.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String input = "'2010-12-04' and '2013-12-03' and wwid='1234'"
String myNewString = input.substring(numberOfPositionsToRemove);
```

In your case it would be:

```
String input = "'2010-12-04' and '2013-12-03' and wwid='1234'"
String myNewString = input.substring(30);
```

Or to make it more dynamic you could use:

```
String input = "'2010-12-04' and '2013-12-03' and wwid='1234'"
int index = input.lastIndexOf("and");
String myNewString = input.substring(index);
```